# How to apply multiple functions to a list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, pipe

I have a list of more than 50 csv files with the same numbers of columns and rows.

I want to find the percentage of missing values for each of the data frames and I have found the code that works fine with a single file which is the following:

```
missing.values <- estaciones2 %>% 
  gather(key = "key", value = "val") %>%
  mutate(is.missing = is.na(val)) %>%
  group_by(key, is.missing) %>%
  summarise(num.missing = n()) %>%
  filter(is.missing==T) %>%
  select(-is.missing) %>%
  arrange(desc(num.missing))
```

Now I want to apply these functions to each of my data frames in my list.

I read that I can use the map function to create a loop and run the code for each of my files in the list, although I am not quite sure how to insert the map function into my code shown above and I have tried the following but doesn't seem right:

```
missing.values <- map(estaciones2, ~ map(estaciones2, ~ estaciones2 %>%
                        gather(key = "key", value = "val") %>%
                        mutate(is.missing = is.na(val)) %>%
                        group_by(key, is.missing) %>%
                        summarise(num.missing = n()) %>%
                        filter(is.missing==T) %>%
                        select(-is.missing) %>%
                        arrange(desc(num.missing)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We need a lambda function (`~`) to loop over the `list` (assuming `estaciones2` is a `list` object).  The `.x` is the data.frame element of the `list` using the lambda call

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
map(estaciones2, ~ .x %>%
                        gather(key = "key", value = "val") %>%
                        mutate(is.missing = is.na(val)) %>%
                        group_by(key, is.missing) %>%
                        summarise(num.missing = n()) %>%
                        filter(is.missing==T) %>%
                        select(-is.missing) %>%
                        arrange(desc(num.missing)))
```

In the OP's code, multiple `map` functions are called on the same `list` element again and again i.e. `estaciones2`